# Using SSL / HTTPS with Meteor?

Tags: ssl, https, meteor

has anyone looked at accepting HTTPS / SSL connections with meteor?

Apologies.

Specifically: how can I set up meteor to accept and work with HTTPS connections?

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Yeah - sorry, this was a bad question. Hopefully that's better.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes *

`HTTPS/SSL` support was added in `v0.3.8`

*source: [Github](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/History.md)*

*Update: Caveats could apply depending on one's use case. See Brett's comment below.

Comment: That "support" comes with the limitation that if you run it outside meteor.com (which you should be doing for production) it's not built-in, and requires a outside proxy. It also doesn't work on meteor.com if you want to use a custom domain.

Comment: Ty. Updated the answer in response to your comment.

Answer (score 3):

I do not believe you can use ssl certificates with Meteor yet.  What you could do is put a node.js based proxy in front of Meteor and handle ssl connections that way.